# Unable to work preview template option for image upload input in admin customizable option

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, magento2.4.6

I had added file upload input in product customizable options area but preview image not display due to preview template file was not loaded it was working well in magento 2.3 version but on in latest magento 2.4.6.

use

> 'previewTmpl'     => 'Vendor_Module/html/image-preview'

in argument for preview html. any have idea/help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.